# In HAML how do you add a class to a submit input (button) on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I've both tried:

```
= f.submit, :class => "form_submit"
```

and

```
= f.submit { :class => "form_submit" }
```

It works just fine with just

```
= f.submit
```

Here is my full rails form.

```
= form_for @organization do |f|
  %div
    .description
      = f.label :description
    = f.text_area :description, :rows => 4, :class => 'ckeditor'
  = f.submit, :class => "form_submit"
```

Comment: try: `= f.submit 'Submit', :class => "form_submit"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
= f.submit 'button_name',:class => "form_submit"
```

Comment: The first comma should be removed, so this answer is incorrect as it is now.

Comment: @kaboom: Are you getting any error because it works fine when class is defined in this format ?

Answer (score 4):

that would be

```
= f.submit 'Button', class: 'custom-class'
```

if you want to let Rails take care of the text, use `nil`

```
= f.submit nil, class: 'custom-class'
```